# How do I call a template function from main in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to call this function, just to get the contents to run:

```
template<class T>
void Pair<T>::display()
```

In my main function I'm trying to do:

```
display();
```

but that is not working. How can I run a template function from main?

Comment: I changed it to int and string now, but it still gives me an error.

Comment: use display<int,int>(10,20)...and follow the same for other data types as well..

Comment: That doesn't work either. Now I have edited it to not take any values in the parameters.

Comment: I tried display<>(); but that isn't working

Comment: It looks like `display` is a member function of a class template. Is it a static member or non-static member?

Comment: `display` seems to be a member of `Pair<T>`: assuming it is a non-`static` member you’ll need an object of a specializationof `Pair<T>`. If it is a  `static` member you’ll need to qualify the call with the appropriate specialization.

Comment: It is a member function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create a `object` of `class Pair` to call function `display()`. Like below:

```
void main(){
       Pair<int> obj;
       obj.display();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost worked. But now I have a new problem. I have a function that says 

void Pair<T>::twopairs(string, string)
{
 //empty
}

that it's interfering with. How do I include both the int and the string?

Comment: error C2244: 'Pair<T>::twopairs': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Comment: You can edit your above question so that everyone can see more obvious code.

Comment: NEVERMIND! It was because I forgot to include the string library in my header file